# Issues with rounding of the column value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe :

DF

```
Date_1      Date_2      b_count
01/09/2019  02/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  03/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  04/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  05/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  06/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  07/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  08/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  09/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  10/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  11/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  12/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  13/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  14/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  15/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  16/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  17/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  18/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  19/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  20/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  21/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  22/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  23/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  24/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  25/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  26/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  27/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  28/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  29/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  30/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  31/08/2019  148
```

I want to generate another column in dataframe individual_count which is to be created with the value of b_count i.e. 148 such that 60% of the count lies in the last 10 days and rest 40% within the remaining days. for example - here date_1 is repeated 30 times, 148 is to be divided in 30 entries such that 60% of the count lie in the last 10 dates of date_2 (in our case from 22/08/2019 to 31/08/2019.

I started with the following :

```
count = 30
arr = [] 
for row in df.iterrows():
    if count == 0:
        count = 30
        continue
    if count >10:
        arr.append(round(0.4 * row.b_Count))
        count = count - 1
    if count <=10:
        arr.append(round(0.6 * row.b_Count))
        count = count - 1

df['new'] = arr
```

The new column assigned the b_count to 60-40 ratio.

Now, to achieve the increasing trend :

```
def add_series(grp):
   n_rows = grp.shape[0]
   val = grp['new'].min()
   s = np.exp(np.linspace(0,1,n_rows)) 
   s = np.round((s * val)/ np.sum(s))
   grp['individual_count'] = s
   return grp

df3 = df.groupby(['Date_1','new']).apply(add_series)
```

This works perfectly as the way I wanted it but with some errors :

if I do :

```
df3.groupby('Flight_Date')['individual_count'].sum()
```

Some of the values are missing, and that is justified because of the round off.

My question lies here :

I do not want to get the loss of b_count while generation of individual_count.

Is there any way that I can ensure the same here. or else, I wanted to assign the missing value to the last entry for date_1 (i.e. 30th entry)

Can anyone help with the same.

Thanks

**EDIT**

Output that I am getting :

```
Date_1  b_Count     individual_count
01/09/2019  148 2
01/09/2019  148 2
01/09/2019  148 2
01/09/2019  148 2
01/09/2019  148 2
01/09/2019  148 2
01/09/2019  148 2
01/09/2019  148 2
01/09/2019  148 3
01/09/2019  148 3
01/09/2019  148 3
01/09/2019  148 3
01/09/2019  148 3
01/09/2019  148 3
01/09/2019  148 4
01/09/2019  148 4
01/09/2019  148 4
01/09/2019  148 4
01/09/2019  148 4
01/09/2019  148 5
01/09/2019  148 5
01/09/2019  148 6
01/09/2019  148 6
01/09/2019  148 7
01/09/2019  148 8
01/09/2019  148 9
01/09/2019  148 10
01/09/2019  148 11
01/09/2019  148 12
01/09/2019  148 14
```

However, if you sum the individual_count, the sum comes to be 147, not 148. I want to assign the missing value to last entry of the date. Please note that the dataframe has many Date_1. I have shared only for one date.

Comment: Your code produces an AttributeError. Also could you please show your expected output? I found your explanation difficult to follow

Comment: @Dan Where is the code crashing? it is working fine for me

Comment: I tried it and i am not missing any values. nevertheless i dont really know what you you are trying to achieve

Comment: @Dan I have edited my question with the output from my code and removing the column new.

Comment: @luigigi Can you please check the edit, I shared the details of the missing value

Comment: @luigigi Let me know if you have any other issues with this

Comment: `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'b_Count'` from the line `arr.append(round(0.4 * row.b_Count))`

Comment: @Dan Not sure what you named the column, but it is working absolutely fine. I believe there is some issue with the naming that you have mentioned

Comment: what's your pandas version (I'm on 0.24.2)? df.iterrows() returns tuples, so the name of the column isn't the issue

Comment: @Dan Mine is '0.25.2'

Comment: @Dan use `row[1].b_count`

Comment: @luigigi Thanks, did you take a look ?

Comment: @vp7 yes. but I dont have solution yet

Comment: @luigigi okok, Can this be achieved, if sum is less, then assign remaining count to last entry of the Date_1.

Comment: @Dan Did you get a chance to take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

You count try sth like this:

```
if df.groupby('Date_1')['individual_count'].sum().values != df.groupby('Date_1')['b_Count'].max().values:
     df.iloc[-1:,2] = df['individual_count'].iloc[-1:] + 1
```

it increment the last item in your specific output. But it wont work dynamicly if you have different `Date_1` values. Maybe you can extend it in some way. Basically you have to change `df.iloc[-1:,2]` to last item of your `Date_1` value

Comment: I have multiple Date_1 values all having 30 entries each.

Comment: Can you please take the above comment into consideration and then edit your suggested answer